# PHP echo multiple HTML links

Tags: php, html

hey guys how to make these php html links codes possible. i have tried many ways and the links do not appear correctly.

```
echo "<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf');"
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>";
```

Comment: What are some of the many ways you have tried and what does the output look like?

Comment: i tried quoting them properly in notepad ++ but it doesnt work can you help me quote them so that the onclick function will work?

Comment: If you would use a proper IDE you will notice that the syntax highligthing is screwed up.

Comment: yeahh the syntax highlighting is screwed up and it wouldnt work properly only the 1st link displays

Comment: Are you sure opening so many popup windows makes user happy and comfortable? If so - ok.

Comment: sorry guys im pretty new to programming bear with me :O

Comment: @dfsq what do you suggest? i was planning to open all the links in a new window with tabs containing the other links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
echo '<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open(\'http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf\')
window.open(\'http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf\')
window.open(\'http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf\')
window.open(\'http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf\')
window.open(\'http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf\');"
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>';
```

You need to escape quotes using backslash.

or

Use Herodoc:

```
echo <<<EOF
<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf');">
Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>
EOF;
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: OMGG THANKS HOW YOU DO THAT!!?

Comment: @Jervis Chionh Here we are using single quotes within single quotes, so we need to escape the quotes else php will interpret it as the end of the quotes and the string will break. So Just escape the quotes with backslashes :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use proper quoting, by replacing `"` with `\"`
2. Separate the expressions in the `onclick` handler using semicolons (between `window.open(...)` and `window.open(...)`.

Code:

```
echo "<a href=\"http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf\" 
onclick=\"window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf');\"
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>";
```

An alternative way is:

```
echo <<<LABEL
<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf');
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf');"
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>
LABEL;
```

Comment: +1 good spot on the semi-colons. I hadn't scrolled that far across :)

Answer (score 1):

You're using double quotes in your echo statement, but also within the content without escaping them. So doe every double quote you use within the statement it should be escaped with a backslash like so:

```
echo "He said "hi there" to me";
```

Becomes:

```
echo "He said \"hi there\" to me";
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would break everything in your onclick event into a javascript function.

```
openLinks(){
    window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf');
    window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf');
    window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf');
    window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf');
    window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf');
}
```

Then just call that function in your onclick().  Makes for cleaner html IMO

```
<a href="link_here" onclick="openLinks();">text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HEREDOC like this:

```
echo <<< EOF
<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf')
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>
EOF;
```

Or else don't even use echo just close the php tag like this (if you're not using any php variable in echo):

```
// end the php code
?>
<a href="http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/1%20CLIST%20AEE2011.pdf" 
onclick="window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/3%20AGO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/4%20CAB%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/6%20PARL%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/7%20PRESCO%20AEE2011.pdf')
window.open('http://www.mof.gov.sg/budget_2011/revenue_expenditure/attachment/21%20PMO%20AEE2011.pdf')
>Government Administration Expenditure Details</a>
<?php // start php code
```